# How to create an AJAX queue for executing multiple php scripts

Tags: php, ajax

I'm looking for a free or for someone to show me some code on how to build a AJAX queue like this one:

http://codecanyon.net/item/ajax-queue-jquery/full_screen_preview/4903957

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function tasks()
 {

     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      xmlhttp.open("GET","a.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="tasks()">


</table>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

how can i get this to display whats on currently on a.php or return success

Comment: There's quite a lot of ways a queue might operate. Does it fire an AJAX operation for each step? Is the purpose of each queued item to wait for a server process to finish? If you would add a more detail in the question, that would be helpful. We usually encourage posters to tell us what they have done so far to solve it, too - have you used jQuery before? You may find `setTimeout()` to be helpful, and the jQuery docs on AJAX calls is very good.

Comment: i really acutally need the functionality of the queue itself i need to process the same function multiple times with different variables and would like it to do it 1 by 1 like that demo

Comment: have you tried rerunning the same function on the `.success` of the ajax call ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be any chance on providing some code on how thats done

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  var urlObj = {
    0: {
        'field': 'f1',
        'url': 'someUrl_1'
    },
    1: {
        'field': 'f2',
        'url': 'someUrl_2'
    },
    2: {
        'field': 'f3',
        'url': 'someUrl_3'
    }
  };

  $.each(urlObj, function(index, value) {
      postRequest(value.field, value.url);
  });
});

function postRequest(field, url){
// here you should make your post request
// and on success criteria
$('.'+field).addClass('success');
}
```

How it will appear - you can see here - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dimitrioglo/295j4ae9/4/)